# No devuelve resultados de la consulta sql

Tags: php, sql

Estoy realizando una consulta a una tabla que contiene 2 relaciones, las agrupo con `GROUP_CONCAT`, y las muestro por un while, desde mi localhost funciona perfectamente, pero ya desde el servidor no me muestra la informacion

Esta es la consulta

```
$acc = "SELECT 
        id_acceso,
        usuarios.nombre, 
        usuarios.apellido, 
        usuarios.cedula, 
        usuarios.usuario, 
        usuarios.correo,
        GROUP_CONCAT(sistemas_disponibles.nombre_sistema SEPARATOR ' // ') AS sistemas,
        GROUP_CONCAT(acceso SEPARATOR ' // ') AS acceso,
        GROUP_CONCAT(edicion SEPARATOR ' // ') AS edicion,
        GROUP_CONCAT(eliminacion SEPARATOR ' // ') AS eliminacion,
        GROUP_CONCAT(agregar SEPARATOR ' // ') AS agregar,
        GROUP_CONCAT(acceso_total SEPARATOR ' // ') AS acceso_total,
        usuarios.id_usuario
        FROM acceso_usuarios
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON acceso_usuarios.id_u = usuarios.id_usuario 
        INNER JOIN sistemas_disponibles ON acceso_usuarios.id_sist = sistemas_disponibles.id_sistema
        GROUP BY usuarios.usuario
        ";
```

Luego simplemente los muestro con un while

```
<?php 
while ($sisre = $resultado -> fetch()) {
?>
<td><?php echo $sisre[4];?></td>
<!-- Etc... ->
<?php
}
?>
```

Desde localhost esto lo devuelve sin ningun problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ya en la web no sucede nada, realizo un var_dump y no me esta trayendo ningun dato

PD: Error de la conexion no es, ya que hay otra consulta que realizo a la tabla relacionada que es `sistemas_disponibles` y no hay ningun problema con esa consulta

Esta es la bd relacionada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualizacion: Al parecer la consulta no me la esta realizando cuando la relaciono a las otras tablas, me los trae si quito la relacion, alguna solucion? si sirve de algo porque no entiendo mucho esta parte, la cardionalidad de las columnas relacionadas me indica 0

ACTUALIZACION:

Aqui estan las 2 bases de datos, muestro La del servidor y luego la local

acceso_usuarios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sistemas_disponibles
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

usuarios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que noto extraño es la cardionalidad, segun el servidor, no me esta relacionando ningun dato desde la bd, pero en el local si las relaciona

EDIT:

```
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'pecpanel_le-suit-principal.acceso_usuarios.id_acceso' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Si realizo la consulta por el localhost este si me devuelve un resultado

Ya pude arreglar el error de que me salian en 2 columnas el id_u
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay algo en los logs de PHP cuando corres la consulta en el host externo?

Comment: No nada, no muestra ningun error

Comment: La base de datos es idéntica en los dos ambientes? No espero que nos digas "sí" sin más. Compruébalo.

Comment: @Alfabravo lo edito con imagenes para que lo puedas ver

Comment: @Alfabravo estoy realizando la consulta directamente de la bd en el servidor y me arroja el error 1055 sin embargo al realizar la misma consulta por el localhost este me devuelve resultados, vere si es un error del servidor

Comment: Ese índice `id_u` está diferente, en un lado abarca dos columnas y en el otro, sólo una. La codificación en un lado es latin1_swedish y en el otro es utf8 (pero eso no es tan relevante ahora mismo). Lo del índice me dice que son diferentes y pues, bien puede pasar que los datos sean diferentes también. Y por favor, **pon el error 1055 completo que esa seguro es la respuesta**

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120037/discussion-between-ernesto-jimenez-and-alfabravo).

Comment: @Alfabravo alli esta todo editado nuevamente

Comment: Ya quedo solucionado gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO: Al intentar realizar la consulta directamente de la base de datos me arroja el error `#1055` que tiene que ver con `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` el cual lo pude solucionar Añadiendo en el `GROUP BY` lo siguiente:

```
GROUP BY id_acceso
```

La misma respuesta me la indicaba el error

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated 
column 'pecpanel_le-suit-principal.acceso_usuarios.id_acceso' which is not 
functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause
```

Esto era debido a que estaba intentando agrupar con GROUP BY un campo que no existia dentro de esa tabla, cuando en realidad debia colocar `id_acceso`

Muchas gracias a @Alfabravo por ayudarme, asi me di cuenta del error

Para el que tenga alguna duda, al final la consulta quedo de la siguiente manera

```
$acc = "SELECT 
        id_acceso,
        usuarios.nombre, 
        usuarios.apellido, 
        usuarios.cedula, 
        usuarios.usuario, 
        usuarios.correo,
        GROUP_CONCAT(sistemas_disponibles.nombre_sistema SEPARATOR ' // ') AS sistemas,
        GROUP_CONCAT(acceso SEPARATOR ' // ') AS acceso,
        GROUP_CONCAT(edicion SEPARATOR ' // ') AS edicion,
        GROUP_CONCAT(eliminacion SEPARATOR ' // ') AS eliminacion,
        GROUP_CONCAT(agregar SEPARATOR ' // ') AS agregar,
        GROUP_CONCAT(acceso_total SEPARATOR ' // ') AS acceso_total,
        usuarios.id_usuario
        FROM acceso_usuarios
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON acceso_usuarios.id_u = usuarios.id_usuario 
        INNER JOIN sistemas_disponibles ON acceso_usuarios.id_sist =     sistemas_disponibles.id_sistema
        GROUP BY id_acceso
        ";
```